# How to control url in jquery mobile which displayed in navigator bar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, single-page-application

I'm developing a jQuery Mobile application which only works under one static url, maybe it calls single page application.

When I use `$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false` in `mobileinit` event, it works well by click links which navigates to other pages, the url never change. But when I enter a complete url with a hashTag, the url changes.For example, enter a url like `http://www.example.com/home/index#catelog/lists` in the navigator bar, url turn to `http://www.example.com/catelog/lists`.It seems that `$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false` dosen't work in this case.

So, how can I control jQuery Mobile still display `http://www.example.com/home/index`?

Answer (score 0):

In head:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        if (window.history && window.history.pushState)
            window.history.pushState('', '', window.location.pathname) 
        else
            window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/#.*$/, '#'); 
    }, true);
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
        // If you need it:
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
    }
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```